# How to use variadic macros with Microsoft VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros

I was trying to use the variadic macros with Microsoft visual studio 2010 and I faced a problem in the preprocessing phase , the complier couldn't translate the expressions correctly.

I searched on the internet for a solution for this problem and I found out that there is some bug in MSV2010 which cause this problem, some programmers suggested  workaround methods to solve this problem and actually [they solved it](http://cplusplus.co.il/2010/07/17/variadic-macro-to-count-number-of-arguments/#comment-742)
 but I am still facing small problem.

Here you are the code I am using.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define VA_NUM_ARGS(…) VA_NUM_ARGS_IMPL_((__VA_ARGS__, 5,4,3,2,1))
#define VA_NUM_ARGS_IMPL_(tuple) VA_NUM_ARGS_IMPL tuple
#define VA_NUM_ARGS_IMPL(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,N,…) N


#define macro_dispatcher(func, ...)   macro_dispatcher_(func, VA_NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))

#define macro_dispatcher_(func, nargs)           macro_dispatcher__(func, nargs)
#define macro_dispatcher__(func, nargs)          func ## nargs

// to verify, run the preprocessor alone (g++ -E):
//VA_NUM_ARGS(x,y,z)


#define max(...)     macro_dispatcher(max, __VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__)

#define max1(a)      a
#define max2(a,b)    ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
#define max3(a,b,c)  max2(max2(a,b),c)
int main(void)
{
    int a,b,c,d,z;
    a=10;
    b=6;
    c=5;

    d=VA_NUM_ARGS(a,b,c);
    z=max(a,b,c);
    printf("Number of Arguments=%d and the max number=%d",d,z);


}
```

`d=VA_NUM_ARGS(a,b,c)` ... Here the code will work correctly and gives the expected data which is d=3;

but for `z=max(a,b,c);` .... the macros will not be translated correctly and the program will show an error

I have run the preprocessor operation and this is what I got as translation for

> z=max(a,b,c)"before preprocessor"
>   z=maxVA_NUM_ARGS_IMPL (a,b,c, 5,4,3,2,1) (a,b,c); "after preprocessor" which isn't the expected as the expcted is 
>   z=max3(a,b,c);

How can I get the correct answer?
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Use the -E option to get the output from the preprocessor to see what it is doing.